# React AsyncSelect onBlur keep input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

With normal react-select V2 `<Select>` I used:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.selectRef.select.onInputBlur = () => {};
  }
```

to keep value of the input  if user clicks somewhere outside. But after changing `<Select>` to `<AsyncSelect>` this doesn't work anymore. Any help?

[**Here is a DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9rpn2ovxq) Enter a value in first input and click outside - value remains. On second input it disappears.

Comment: The second input doesn't seem to have any options there?

Comment: Thats just a demo like that, but it is not related to the issue anyway. Even though it doesnt have any options, i still need to keep the value

Comment: But the demo doesn't show the behavior you're having an issue with, so how is it helpful?

Comment: @Colin omg are you serious? Read again - **"Enter a value in first input and click outside - value remains. On second input it disappears."**

Comment: There's no value in the second input to select though?

Comment: Why I have to repeat you everything twice? Read everything again, please.

Comment: I commented out options from the first one. Happy?

Comment: Yep, much clearer – thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `componentDidMount()` to the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.selectRef.select.onInputBlur = () => {};
  this.asyncRef.select.select.onInputBlur = () => {};
}
```

The normal select and the async selects have different structures, which is why this is necessary.